# Why do I need Sum and Bank class to calculate Money?

Tags: oop

I am reading [Test Driven Development: By Example](http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-By-Example/dp/product-description/0321146530). I am on chapter 13. Chapter 12 and 13 introduced `Plus` operation to `Money` object. A `Money` object can plus by other `Money` object.

The author added two classes (`Bank` and `Sum`) and one interface (`IExpression`) to the solution. This is the class diagram of the final solution.

[image: Class diagram]

`Money` store amount and currency for example 10 USD, 5 BAHT, 20 CHF. The `Plus` method returns `Sum` object.

```
public class Money : IExpression
{
    private const string USD = "USD";
    private const string CHF = "CHF";

    public int Amount { get; protected set; }

    public string Currency { get; private set; }

    public Money(int value, string currency)
    {
        this.Amount = value;
        this.Currency = currency;
    }

    public static Money Dollar(int amount)
    {
        return new Money(amount, USD);
    }

    public static Money Franc(int amount)
    {
        return new Money(amount, CHF);
    }

    public Money Times(int times)
    {
        return new Money(this.Amount * times, this.Currency);
    }

    public IExpression Plus(Money money)
    {
        return new Sum(this, money);
    }

    public Money Reduce(string to)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var money = obj as Money;

        if (money == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        }

        return this.Amount == money.Amount &&
            this.Currency == money.Currency;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Amount: {0} {1}", this.Amount, this.Currency);
    }
}
```

`Sum` store two Money objects which come from constructor arguments. It has one method `Reduce` that return new `Money` object (create new object by add amount of two object)

```
public class Sum : IExpression
{
    public Money Augend { get; set; }

    public Money Addend { get; set; }

    public Sum(Money augend, Money addend)
    {
        this.Augend = augend;
        this.Addend = addend;
    }

    public Money Reduce(string to)
    {
        var amount = this.Augend.Amount + this.Addend.Amount;

        return new Money(amount, to);
    }
}
```

`Bank` has one method - `Reduce`. It just call Reduce method of incoming `IExpression` argument.

```
public class Bank
{
    public Money Reduce(IExpression source, string to)
    {
        return source.Reduce(to);
    }
}
```

`IExpression` is an interface that implemented by `Money` and `Sum`.

```
public interface IExpression
{
    Money Reduce(string to);
}
```

These are my questions.

1. `Bank` does nothing good for the solution at this stage. Why do I need it?
2. Why do I need `Sum` since I can create and return Money object inside `Plus` of the class `Money` (Like what the author did with `Times`)?
3. What is the purpose of Bank and Sum? (Right now, it doesn't make any sense for me)
4. I think `Reduce` sound strange for me as the method name. Do you think it is a good name? (please suggest)

Comment: If you vote close for this question. Please tell me why you think it should close. :) Thank you.

Comment: I voted to close.  I don't think it's a good question, because you haven't finished the bloody book yet.

Comment: So, you suggest me to follow him and I will understand the reason why he did this when I finished the book, right? (I don't want to sound rude. I ask because I always look for reasons and make myself crystal clear on the topic before I move on to the next chapter.)

Comment: I don't know what you'll understand and what you won't.  I know nothing about your level of competence or if you have enough context to "get" this book.  I don't want to sound rude, but it might not be possible achieve clarity before you move on.  It might take a second read.  Or Kent Beck might be full of it.  I haven't read that book, but I've read others by him.

Comment: Thank you @duffymo I think I might read it once to get the overview and get my hand on. Then I read it again to make me more understand of what the author tries to teach. :) Thank you for your answer and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep reading.  Kent Beck is a very smart guy.  He either has a very good reason why he created the example that way, and it  will be clear later on, or it's a poor solution.

"Reduce" is a very good name if [map-reduce](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html) is the ultimate goal.